# Can't enable Bluetooth in 13.10

Tags: bluetooth

I've been having a really hard time with this one...

I've had my ASUS X301A since last year, solely under Ubuntu 12.04 until recently (a month or so), when I switched to 13.04. More recently, I bought a bluetooth headset which works like a charm with my phone and reminded me that I had bluetooth on my PC.

Getting to the point now: I can't seem to figure out how to get bluetooth working. When I try to enable it via GUI, it doesn't do *anything at all* :

EDIT: I upgraded to 13.10 and re-ran the checks, here's what I get now :

```sh
jmcomets ~ $ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
jmcomets ~ $ hcitool dev    
Devices:
jmcomets ~ $ hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device
jmcomets ~ $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5165 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
jmcomets ~ $ dmesg | grep -i blue
[   27.325857] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   27.325879] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   27.325887] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   27.325889] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   27.325895] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   27.484857] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   27.484870] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   27.484872] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   28.008427] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   28.008431] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   28.008440] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
jmcomets ~ % lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
```

Even better now, bluetooth doesn't show up at all with `rfkill`.

Comment: I presume your bluetooth adapter is USB? isn't it? Do it works in a live session?

Comment: I believe it's built-in directly in the PC ([specs](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X301A/#specifications) here). I don't see what a "live session" is so I can't tell you if it works.

Comment: If it's built in then replace the lsusb output with `lspci`, and live session means a live CD/USB.

Comment: I edited the question adding lspci output

Comment: And the live cd? Did you tried 12.04 live cd? What changes between both?

Comment: Check the bios, maybe it is disabled there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I am short in time because I am at work. I can give you a hint and maybe an assumed solution ;). I had trouble with my BT adapter (which is USB) as well two weeks ago. Mine is:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

But I had exactly the same symptoms as you described it wit 14.04 LTS. After a long research I found out that the bluetooth drivers became a little bit buggy some months ago. It has something to do with a set mode when the driver tries to initialize the BT device. As far as I can remember it was a Bugfix that turned out to not work very well with some devices.

See [BT kernel driver became unstable](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60824). There is also a link to a patch that made my BT dongle work again: [Fix unstable BT driver patch](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth-next.git/commit/?id=f9f462faa02777f497eb25255683a94e0c054de6)

I did not apply the patch to my kernel because I am short of time for the moment and BT is not so important for me but since the patch is applied to next Ubuntu kernel for 14.04 LTS I installed this kernel and BT worked perfectly again. Since I have a NVidia Graphic Card I could not use this kernel because nvidia 304-updates package does not work with this release, but on commandline all worked fine.

If it is possible for you switch to 14.04 LTS and wait for the next kernel release or download kernel-source package, apply the patch and compile a kernel of your own.

Hope it helped, I wish you good luck

Comment: Thanks for the (late) answer, I actually figured out that my pc doesn't have a bluetooth device, although the specs I had found said there was one... Long story short, problem solved.